# Generic findAll query based on Criteria API generates wrong SQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I've recently adapted a bigger project. The first thing I did was to update the 3 year old dependencies (Hibernate from 4.1.4 to 5.2.10, java 7 to 8, tomee 1.7.4 to 7.0.3). 
But as I'm not exactly familiar with Hibernate upgrading has been a challenge as I've run into numerous problems. Whilst I was able to resolve most of them up until now I can't wrap my head around the current one. There is an existing generic function to fetch all Entities from a table.
A query is created based on a criteria but the raw SQL query seems to be wrong and thus no data is returned; More precise: the table and column names are not replaced in it. The debug print you can find in the code below results in the following:

```
select generatedAlias0 from TestReferenceEntity as generatedAlias0
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_TYPE_REF")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "findTestEntityByName", query = "SELECT bt FROM TestReferenceEntity bt WHERE bt.name = :name") })
public class TestReferenceEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    public static final String FIND_BY_NAME = "findTestEntityByName";
    public static final String TYPENAME_PARAM_NAME = "name";

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "PREFIX")
    private String prefix;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "IDENT_REGEXP")
    private String regexp;
}
```

AbstractDao:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<E extends AbstractEntity> implements AbstractService<E>  {
    public static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "MeineJpaPU";

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDao.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    private E entityClass; //This is set elsewhere

    public List<E> findAll() {
        return findAll(1, 1000);
    }

    public List<E> findAll(final int page, final int rowsPerPage) {
        final Class<E> clazz = getEntityClass(); //TestReferenceEntity.class
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<E> criteria = cb.createQuery(clazz);
        final Root<E> r = criteria.from(clazz);
        criteria.select(r);

        final TypedQuery<E> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteria);
        query.setFirstResult(page - 1);
        query.setMaxResults((page - 1) * rowsPerPage);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>> " + query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString());

        return query.getResultList(); //Empty - but there is data in the table
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MeineJpaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/jdbc/PROJECTNAME</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My best guess is that I'm missing some key parts (annotations?) added in later versions of hibernate. After all the version we used was a bit older.
I've researched this behavior but could not find anything matching my problem. Hibernate's migration guides didn't help either.

I hope you can guide me towards a solution. Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: care to share the actual SQL generated, that you say is incorrect? because you post JPQL seemingly.

Comment: It looks like no SQL statement is executed. I've enabled query logging on my MySQL instance to verify this. It's funny that no exception is thrown either.
How would I go about with debugging even more? Isn't the query I printed the one which would be executed? As mentioned I only recently adapted this project and aren't familiar enough with hibernate to properly debug / fix it.

Comment: SQL is always executed (or at least should be) when you call `getResultList()` (or at least is with the JPA provider I use, and it isn't the one you chose). If it isn't then you report a bug in your JPA provider

Comment: Using `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />` there is no message in the console except my debug print (And as previously stated no query against the database). I'm using openejb-jpa-integration:7.0.3, openjpa:2.4.2 and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final (newest version each)

Comment: How can you be using OpenJPA when you say you're using Hibernate?! They are BOTH JPA providers, so decide which you are using

Comment: I am using hibernate. As I said I'm not the one who started that project - the exclusion for openjpa was commented out. I've now excluded it. However, the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll()` (Without parameters) passes 1 for page.

```
query.setMaxResults((page - 1) * rowsPerPage);
```

results in `query.setMaxResults(0)`.

There seems to have been change in the Hibernate implementation as you stated it's been working fine before.